# Having Trouble using two Nvidia Jetson nano developer kits using Chapel

Tags: nvidia, chapel

I'm using Chapel for a project in my class and I am trying to do multilocale executution with my two Nvidia Jetson nano boards.
Following this tutorial https://chapel-lang.org/docs/usingchapel/multilocale.html#readme-multilocale.
I keep getting errors when I try to run the hello executable.
I run the code by doing "./hello -nl 2"

Here is the error message I keep getting

```
*** GASNET WARNING(Node 0): int sendPacket(ep_t, amudp_msg_t*, size_t, en_t, packet_type) returning an error code: AM_ERR_RESOURCE (Problem with requested resource)
  from function sendPacket
  at /home/chico/chapel-1.20.0/third-party/gasnet/gasnet-src/other/amudp/amudp_reqrep.cpp:112
  reason: Invalid argument

*** GASNET WARNING(Node 0): int AMUDP_RequestGeneric(amudp_category_t, ep_t, amudp_node_t, handler_t, void*, size_t, uintptr_t, int, va_list, uint8_t, uint8_t) returning an error code: AM_ERR_RESOURCE (Problem with requested resource)
  at /home/chico/chapel-1.20.0/third-party/gasnet/gasnet-src/other/amudp/amudp_reqrep.cpp:1045

GASNet gasnetc_AMRequestShort encountered an AM Error: AM_ERR_RESOURCE(3)
  at /home/chico/chapel-1.20.0/third-party/gasnet/gasnet-src/udp-conduit/gasnet_core.c:827
*** WARNING (proc 0): GASNet gasnetc_AMRequestShort returning an error code: GASNET_ERR_RESOURCE (Problem with requested resource)
  at /home/chico/chapel-1.20.0/third-party/gasnet/gasnet-src/udp-conduit/gasnet_core.c:829
*** FATAL ERROR(Node 1): An active message was returned to sender,
    and trapped by the default returned message handler (handler 0):
Error Code: ECONGESTION: Congestion at destination endpoint                
Message type: AM_REQUEST_M
Destination: (127.0.0.1:52171) (0)
Handler: 64
Tag: 0x7f0001010000629e
Arguments(5): 0x00000000  0x00000001  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000009  
Aborting...
*** Caught a fatal signal (proc 1): SIGABRT(6)
NOTICE: Before reporting bugs, run with GASNET_BACKTRACE=1 in the environment to generate a backtrace. 
NOTICE: We recommend linking the debug version of GASNet to assist you in resolving this application issue.
bash: line 1:  1658 Aborted                 (core dumped) env 'AMUDP_SLAVE_ARGS=1,JetsonNano:52561,' './hello_real' '-nl' '2' '-E' 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr/local/cuda/lib64' '-E' 'LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:' '-E' 'SSH_CONNECTION=132.241.216.227 8794 192.168.1.20 22' '-E' 'LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s' '-E' 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8' '-E' 'CHPL_REGEXP=none' '-E' 'OLDPWD=/home/chico/chapel-1.20.0' '-E' 'CHPL_GMP=none' '-E' 'LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-7' '-E' 'XDG_SESSION_ID=132' '-E' 'USER=chico' '-E' 'PWD=/home/chico' '-E' 'HOME=/home/chico' '-E' 'SSH_CLIENT=132.241.216.227 8794 22' '-E' 'CHPL_COMM=gasnet' '-E' 'XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop' '-E' 'CHPL_MEM=cstdlib' '-E' 'GASNET_SSH_SERVERS=JetsonNano JetsonNano2' '-E' 'SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark' '-E' 'SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/4' '-E' 'MAIL=/var/mail/chico' '-E' 'TERM=xterm-256color' '-E' 'SHELL=/bin/bash' '-E' 'CHPL_TASKS=fifo' '-E' 'CHPL_LLVM=none' '-E' 'SHLVL=1' '-E' 'GASNET_SPAWNFN=S' '-E' 'MANPATH=/home/chico/chapel-1.20.0/man:' '-E' 'CHPL_HOME=/home/chico/chapel-1.20.0' '-E' 'LOGNAME=chico' '-E' 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1001/bus' '-E' 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1001' '-E' 'PATH=/home/chico/.cargo/bin:/home/chico/.local/bin:/home/chico/chapel-1.20.0/bin/linux64-aarch64:/home/chico/chapel-1.20.0/util:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin/:/opt/spark/bin:/opt/spark/sbin' '-E' 'LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s' '-E' '_=./hello'
```

It works if I only use the localhost.

Note: I have been using mpy4py with python across my two boards and it works. Also, I'm using an ansible playbook to sync both boards across the network.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this system, so the first thought would be to follow GASNet's advice and enable debugging and backtracing.  This can be done for Chapel by (a) setting GASNET_BACKTRACE=1 and CHPL_COMM_DEBUG=1 in your environment, (b) re-building the Chapel runtime in this mode (`cd $CHPL_HOME && [g]make`), (c) recompiling and re-running your program.

Comment: Also note that since this is likely to require some back-and-forth due to its unfamiliarity to us, it might be more appropriate to file as a Chapel GitHub issue (https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues).  We could then post the answer here if it seems likely to be helpful to others.

Comment: Shoot, I missed one step in the "how to enable debugging" advice above:  Sometime before step (b), you'll need to do `cd $CHPL_HOME/runtime && make clean`.

Comment: Okay just posted it on the Chapel GitHub issue, I went through the steps and I got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symptoms reported here relate to a failure occurring during GASNet initialization in which communication fails to be established between the multiple processes that implement the Chapel program.  Unfortunately, there are a number of factors that could cause this sort of failure mode, such as incorrect `/etc/hosts` entries, firewalls preventing communication, etc.  Users running into this sort of issue should feel free to open up an issue on the [Chapel GitHub issues page](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues) to try and resolve it.

To see the discussion and resolution of the problem in this specific case, readers may wish to refer to Chapel [issue #14581](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/14581) and specifically [this comment](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/14581#issuecomment-562710660).